# Android: how to use ValueAnimator

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to do a translate animation using this following

```
public static void move(TextView view){

    ValueAnimator va = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, 3f);
    int mDuration = 3000; //in millis
    va.setDuration(mDuration);
    va.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {

        }
    });
    va.setRepeatCount(5);
    va.start();
}
```

But I don't know how to use onAnimationUpdate method.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Just apply the animation. You can get the values from `animation` object. Alternatively you can use `ObjectAnimator` this class will automatically apply the animated values to the property of the given object.

Comment: @Ahmada Beye // Pro tip; call 'va.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());' for an even smoother animation.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

If you really, *really*, ***really*** want to use `ValueAnimator` for animating translation of the `View` you can do it this way (finishing your example, assuming you meant `translationX`.

**Bare in mind that you're animating translation from 0px to 3px, so you probably won't see much difference.**

```kotlin
fun move(view: TextView) {
  val va = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, 3f)
  va.duration = 3000 //in millis
  va.addUpdateListener { animation -> view.translationX = animation.animatedValue as Float }
  va.repeatCount = 5
  va.start()
}
```

Comment: Thank you  so much that's what I really, really, **really**  need

Comment: Please, why the emphasis on the really. Is it a cumbersome approach or a bad practice? Rookie Question BTW.

Comment: @FelixFavour because this is not optimal way to perform translation animation on a view (I personally prefer view.animate()). Have a look at [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N_x7SV3I3P0) by the animation framework team.

Answer (score 13):

ValueAnimator is a great tool for making animations. Usually we have three steps:

Step 1- Create your ValueAnimator class by

```
ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(start value, end value);
```

Step 2- Adding one update listener and overriding at least onAnimationUpdate() function

```
animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            float value = (float) animator.getAnimatedValue();
            
            //this value should be used to update properties of views.
            //just don't forget to run invalidate function of your views 
              // to redraw them. 
        }
    });
```

Step 3-

```
animator.start();
```